# Beginner way to validate strings/doubles in Java

Tags: java

I am in week 7 of an "Intro to Java Programming" class. Week 5's assignment was:
"Write a program that prompts the user to enter a Social Security number in the format DDD-DD-DDDD, where D is a digit (0-9).  Your program should check whether the input is valid."

I originally submitted nothing due to the book ("Intro to Java Programming" by Y Daniel Liang) and my instructor not really making sense when discussing converting doubles to strings and validating their formatting.

I was hoping YouTube, Google, or some other source would help me figure this out; however, the solutions  include "Regex" and other utilities we haven't gotten close to discussing yet. I will get an F for anything I can't replicate and explain on Tuesday so really in-depth, veteran solutions are out of the question here.

Any suggestions for how I can quickly catch myself up to speed on simple validations/conversions of strings?

Comment: OK, break the problem down. What does a social security have? dashes, ok, can they be anywhere? How many dashes and numbers can you have? I think you should start out with assessing the problem come up with something, a working code example, even if it doesn't work and come back.

Comment: I think this question is a little bit too broad as it currently stands. Could you add some of the things you've tried? Even if they don't work, it's still useful to see the sort of things you're struggling with.

Comment: I know this is horrific and incorrect - I have an A in this class but don't recall this being covered. We haven't discussed "string validation" since the assignment was due 10/8/2019.

            System.out.print("Enter an SSN: ");
            String inputSSN = input.nextLine();
                 
            if (inputSSN.isNumber()) {
            System.out.println("Input is a valid Social Security Number.");
            }

Comment: Use: `String ssn = scanner.nextLine();`. Then to validate the input use the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method with a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex): `if (ssn.matches("^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$")) {` or use this regex: `if (ssn.matches("^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$")) {`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd the problem with your suggestion is that we haven't covered Regex. My solution currently validates that all characters that shouldn't be hyphens are validated to ensure they're digits with the following:

"if (!Character.isDigit(one)) {
        System.out.println(inputSSN + " is an invalid Social Security Number.");
        } "

I need to validate that characters 4 and 7 of the string are hyphens.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. So 1) Add your code attempts to your post 2) All the comments regarding the note you will get are useless, just ask your some urgency 3) Even if you did not study regex, it is a part of a class researching, so you could add something you did not study although there is a clear instruction to not to do it. If it is the case, then try your best and show us where are you stacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this (the long way) using a **for** loop and several **if** statements. You definitely want to use the [Character.isDigit()](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-character-isdigit-method) method within your **if** statement conditions.

You need to iterate through the SSN string supplied by the User one character at a time so use of the [String.charAt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm) method is important here as well. Here is one way you might go about it:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputSSN = "";

while (inputSSN.equals("")) {
    System.out.print("Enter a Social Security Number: --> ");
    inputSSN = input.nextLine();

    // Validate SSN...
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSSN.length(); i++) {
        // Validate the first set of 3 digits
        if (i >= 0 && i <= 2) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(inputSSN.charAt(i))) {
                inputSSN = "";
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }

        // Validate the first hyphen
        if (i == 3 && inputSSN.charAt(i) != '-') {
            inputSSN = "";
            break;
        }

        // Validate the second set of 2 digits
        if (i >= 4 && i <= 5) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(inputSSN.charAt(i))) {
                inputSSN = "";
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }

        // Validate the second hyphen
        if (i == 6 && inputSSN.charAt(i) != '-') {
            inputSSN = "";
            break;
        }

        // Validate the third set of 4 digits
        if (i >= 7 && i <= 10) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(inputSSN.charAt(i))) {
                inputSSN = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Validate that the SSN is the right length
    if (inputSSN.length() != 11) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Social Security Number!" + System.lineSeparator());
        inputSSN = "";
    }
}

System.out.println(inputSSN + " is a valid Social Security Number.");
```